# Should I run "dpkg -i" after running "apt-get install -f" in case of unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Let's say I have downloaded `xxx.deb` and tried to install it using `sudo dpkg -i xxx.deb` however it has failed due unmet dependencies. Then I ran `sudo apt-get install -f`

Should I run `sudo dpkg -i xxx.deb` again just to be sure or does `sudo apt-get install -f` take care of it for me?

OS: 14.04 LTS x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `apt-get install -f`, if it succeeded in installing dependencies, will run all remaining steps left in the installation of the new package (and any other pending installations). `dpkg -i` will just be repeating that work. If `apt-get` failed, then running `dpkg -i` isn't going to do anything useful.

Note that you shouldn't have to do this if you have the Ubuntu Software Center installed. It can handle deb files and install dependencies as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I know USC does that but I don't like GUI apps.